# Variable is null but it really isn't?

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I am writing a small app using Java + JavaFX.

In the controller class I have my `PasswordField`:

```
@FXML
PasswordField password;
```

And a field to temporarily store the password:

```
private String rootPassword;
```

Then I have a method to handle the password:

```
private void handlePasswordField() {
    if (!password.getText().isEmpty()) {
        this.rootPassword = password.getText();
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.initOwner(nbtcInstaller.getPrimaryStage());
        alert.setTitle("No password");
        alert.setHeaderText("No password provided");
        alert.setContentText("Please enter a new ROOT password");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

and the method that launches after the "install" button is pressed:

```
@FXML
private void handleCommand() {
    handlePasswordField();
    doAllTheOtherStuff();
    Platform.exit();
}
```

When I provide no password, I get the alert, but the `doAllTheOtherStuff()` is still launched. What can I do to prevent it from launching the `doAllTheOtherStuff()` method when there is no password provided?

Comment: Null is not the same as empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make the method return a boolean:

```
private boolean handlePasswordField() {
    if (!password.getText().isEmpty()) {
        this.rootPassword = password.getText();
        return true;
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.initOwner(nbtcInstaller.getPrimaryStage());
        alert.setTitle("No password");
        alert.setHeaderText("No password provided");
        alert.setContentText("Please enter a new ROOT password");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then check it out when necessary:

```
@FXML
private void handleCommand() {
    if(handlePasswordField()) {
        doAllTheOtherStuff();
    }
    Platform.exit();
}
```

A final suggestion would be changing the name of the method to be clearer, but this is only optional:

```
private boolean isPasswordValid() {
```

Then the `if` would be more natural:

```
if(isPasswordValid()) {
```